# HighPoint RocketRAID 2740 passthrough

Tags: linux, raid, firmware, passthrough

I'm currently extending my server and about to buy a HBA.
I stumbled across the HighPoint RocketRAID 2740 which is quite cheap at the moment.

I am going to extend an existing MDRaid + LVM installation so I don't need any sort of Hardwareraid functionality.

Is this card capable of directly passing all connected discs to the OS ?

While using google I found out that there seemed to be a non raid firmware, but it is not directly available on the official download page and allthough I found one on hightechs servers here:
http://www.highpoint-tech.cn/China_new/rr276x-274x_download_U.htm
I'm unsure if it still works.

Can someone confirm this card is usable for my situation ?

If not: What are my alternatives ?

I need to connect 16x SATA drives (using 4 SFF-8087 backplanes) to a PCIe x16 2.0 slot in a cheap way.